# How does wait.Until work?

Tags: selenium

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(_browser, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0));
IWebElement textBoxByName = wait.Until(d => d.FindElement(By.Name((m.Groups["MethodValue"].Value))));
textBoxByName.SendKeys(m.Groups["Content"].Value.Replace("<SP>", " "));
```

I want to use wait.Until to wait until the element presents and found by selenium but it doesn't work and will through exception that the element can't be found because the element hasn't presented.

But if I use implicit wait to wait for certain seconds until the element displays I can find the element.

So I wonder how explicit wait works and if what is the correct way to wait until and element displays automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set

```
TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0)
```

so it waits only for 0 seconds, i.e., doesnt wait at all. Try increasing that number and it should work.

Comment: Oh I see. Thx! But can I wait until the element presents automatically? If I set the time for TimeSpan what is the difference with implicit wait?

Comment: Not much of the difference in this case. But ImplicitWait is set for the life of the driver instance and will be same. You can provide ExplicitWait for some particular condition.

Comment: Got it. Could u explain more what "is set for the life of the driver" means? Ty so much

Comment: When you set the implicit wait, the wait is applied every time you do a findElement or findElements.

Comment: Cool ty. Is there a way to wait it automatically?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90076/discussion-between-vikas-neha-ojha-and-benjamin-ruan).